# How to save custom option if "No Results Match" with .select?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, form-helpers

I'm still debating whether `text_field` or `select` is the more appropriate form helper.

With `text_field` you can save your custom text.

With `select` you choose from a list provided.

I want a **hybrid** where when a user clicks on the field, a drop down menu appears with options, but the user can ignore it and type away his own custom option.

I tried **[select2](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails)** and looked into a variety of jquery plugins provided **[here](http://www.unheap.com/section/inputs-forms/selectboxes/)**, but if you type a custom option it will give back "No results matched" and then you're unable to save it.

What's the best way to create this hybrid? I'm using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply utilize `createSearchChoice` option of select2 which will add new choice rather than showing "no results". See it running at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQ8Fw/674/)

Html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="tags" style="width: 300px"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var lastResults = [];

$("#tags").select2({
    //multiple: true,
    placeholder: "Please enter tags",
    //tokenSeparators: [","],
    ajax: {
        multiple: true,
        url: "/echo/json/",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                json: JSON.stringify({results: [{id: "foo", text:"foo"},{id:"bar", text:"bar"}]}),
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            lastResults = data.results;
            return data;
        }
    },
    createSearchChoice: function (term) {
        var text = term + (lastResults.some(function(r) { return r.text == term }) ? "" : " (new)");
        return { id: term, text: text };
    },
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XQ8Fw/674/

Comment: Updated my answer, all you need to do is remove `multiple` from the code. Hope now it works they way you wanted to work.

Comment: For the life of me I couldn't get this to work with ruby on rails. I opened up a new question where I narrow in more specifically on what's holding me back. But for the purposes of this question - you did good my friend.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps out you.
It is straightforward and simple.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  modify();
})

function modify() {
  $('input').val($('select').val());
  output();
}

function output() {
  $('p').text('value: ' + $('input').val());
}

$('input').on('click', function() {
  $(this).select()
}).on('blur', function() {
  output();
})

modify();
```

```css
select {
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
  height: 23px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 0;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 17px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
p {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <select>
    <option selected="selected" value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
  <p>value:</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you know how instead of default value being "Wednesday" it would be a placeholder text, "Enter Challenge." And how I can be translate your code into a ruby on rails project. Thanks for your help! I think you're definitely on the right track :)